# get session expire time

Tags: session, cakephp, session-timeout

How to get the actual `Session` timeout or its expiry time in controller?

I tried `CakeSession::$sessionTime`, `CakeSession::$time`, `CakeSession::$cookieLifeTime` but it returned `FALSE`, `FALSE` and `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

For getting session timeout,use below code

```
Configure::read('Session.timeout');
```

Comment: Look at your core.php for Configure::write('Session.timeout', '120');
If its commented then remove commented

Comment: I read on cookbook, the actual expiry time depends on `Session.timeout`and `Security.level`.. So how to get the actual value?